# What is the largest and smallest Hex Floating Point Literal value that can be represented in IEEE 754-2008 64-bit binary (radix 2) format?

Tags: floating-point, literals, ieee-754

I know that in IEEE 754-2008 64-bit binary (radix 2) format the largest **Decimal Floating Point Number** that can be represented is **1.7976931348623157E+308** and the smallest is **4.94065645841246544E-325**. So the values that results from converting this to hex is not the largest and smallest **Hex Floating Point** value?

Comment: Hexadecimal floating-point notation for the largest finite IEEE-754 binary64 value is `0x1.FFFFFFFFFFFFFp+1023`. Hexadecimal floating-point notation for the smallest positive IEEE-754 binary64 value is `0x1p-1074`. Are those what you are looking for? Your value for the latter is off; the exponent should be −324, not −325.

Comment: The term "Decimal Floating Point" is confusing here, hopefully you compare it with "Hex Floating Point", so you are talking about "**Binary Floating Point**" represented as decimal and hexadecimal. The term "Decimal Floating Point" has usually [this meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest finite value has an exponent of `11111111110` (because the largest one is reserved for INFs and NaNs) which means , representing 2<sup>2046 - 1023</sup> = 2<sup>+1023</sup> , and a significand of all ones:

```
0 11111111110 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112
```

which is 0x7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF in raw hex form and `0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023`. You can check this with [float.exposed](https://float.exposed/0x7fefffffffffffff) or [floating-point-converter](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)

It can also be calculated like this: the significand of binary64 contains 52 explicit bits and a hidden 1 bit, so the largest significand is `1.fffffffffffff`. There are 11 exponent bits, allowing for the largest exponent of *2<sup>11</sup> - 1 - 1023 - 1 = 1023*. That means the largest value is `0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023`

Similarly the smallest non-zero normalized number has a exponent pattern of `00000000001`, representing 2<sup>1 - 1023</sup> = 2<sup>-1022</sup> and significand = 0, so

```
0 00000000001 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
= 0x0000000000000001
= 0x1p-1022
```

The smallest non-zero subnormal number has exponent of all zeros and significand = 1:

```
0 00000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012
= 0x0010000000000000
= 0x1p-1074
```